# Deployment failed because the application specification file specifies an unsupported operating system

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-code-deploy

Using AWS code deploy service to deploy application on Linux server on ec2 instance. Keep getting error message

> The deployment failed because the application specification file specifies an unsupported operating system (). Specify either "linux" or "windows" in the os section of the AppSpec file, and then try again.

I have created appspec.yml file and clearly mentioned

```
version: 0.0
os: linux
```

However, still keep getting this error on BeforeInstall event on code deploy.

I have verified code deploy agent on the ec2 server. The service is up and running.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Are you editing that file from a Windows box? I have seen problems with Windows line endings cause similar issues. Make sure you are using proper Linux line endings in that file.